# How to find the matching element in a list from different list? in C#

Tags: c#, linq

How to find the matching element in array from different array? in  C#

I have different varities of products and dynamically created attributes of every variety

```
public class SingleVariety
    {
        [JsonProperty("varietyId")]
        public int VarietyId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("varietyName")]
        public string VarietyName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sku")]
        public string Sku { get; set; }

        public List<SingleAttribute> Attributes { get; set; }= new List<SingleAttribute>();

    }

   public class SingleAttribute
    {

        [JsonProperty("attributeName")]
        public string AttributeName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("attributeValue")]
        public string AttributeValue { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("varietyId")]
        public int VarietyId { get; set; }

    }
```

and I have a filter array and trying to determine the selected variety based on the selection of attributes

sample variety model

```
 var varities = new List<SingleVariety>() { 
                new SingleVariety { 
                    Sku="testsku", VarietyId=1, VarietyName="test 1", 
                Attributes = new List<SingleAttribute> 
                { new SingleAttribute { AttributeName = "Size", AttributeValue="Large" },
                    new SingleAttribute{ AttributeName = "Color", AttributeValue = "Red"} 
                }},
                new SingleVariety {
                    Sku="testsku2", VarietyId=2, VarietyName="test 2",
                Attributes = new List<SingleAttribute>
                { new SingleAttribute { AttributeName = "Size", AttributeValue="Small" },
                    new SingleAttribute{ AttributeName = "Color", AttributeValue = "Red"}
                }},
                new SingleVariety {
                    Sku="testsku3", VarietyId=3, VarietyName="test 3",
                Attributes = new List<SingleAttribute>
                { new SingleAttribute { AttributeName = "Size", AttributeValue="Very Large" },
                    new SingleAttribute{ AttributeName = "Color", AttributeValue = "Black"}
                }}

            };
```

sample filter array

```
 var filterObject = new List<SingleAttribute> { 
                new SingleAttribute { AttributeName = "Size", AttributeValue="Large" },
            new SingleAttribute{ AttributeName = "Color", AttributeValue = "Red"} 
            };
```

variety with variety id 1 should be found because the filter object contains size=large, and color=red anyone can help me this?

I have used predicates, linq but I was not successfull

Comment: Hi Daisy. It would be great if you can provide sample code for what you have tried so far with predicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One (flexible) way of doing this would be to chain your queries:

```
//Start with the whole set
var results = (IEnumerable<SingleVariety>)varities;

for (int i = 0; i < filterObject.Count; i++)
{
    var filter = filterObject[i];
    //Refine with each attribute match
    results = results.Where(i => i.Attributes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AttributeName == filter.AttributeName)?.AttributeValue == filter.AttributeValue);
}
```

If we inspect the output:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Count: {results.Count()}");
foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {result.VarietyName}, Id: {result.VarietyId}");
}
```

We get the following:

```
Count: 1
Name: test 1, Id: 1
```

We cast it to the `IEnumerable<SingleVariety>` interface so that the chaining can work since the Linq methods will return that type.

A couple of things worth noting is that this will support any number of filters **but** it will be an `and` operation.

Technically, you don't need the `filter` variable. You could just do it inline but I like to write code this way for clarity.